# How do I install the global appmenu (mac menu)?

Tags: 10.10, appmenu

Anyone knows how to install globalmenu on Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead use this:

```
sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk indicator-appmenu indicator-applet-appmenu
```

Add it to your panel by right clicking on the panel, choosing Add to Panel and then select Indicator Applet Appmenu

I got this from [OMGUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/customizing-ubuntu-10-10-with-a-dock-new-icon-theme-effects-global-menu-and-more/)

Hope that helps!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, indicator-applet-menu is not entirely equivalent to globalmenu.  The main difference afaict is that the application name, which usually shows up in the window's title bar does not show up in the upper tray.  I'm sure this is a bug/oversight in i-a-m (which I will now submit a bug report on), but it's an important part of what globalmenu does.  It tells you which application has the focus.

Still, it's nice to see i-a-m in Maverick and I'll be switching my desktops over to it.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/wiki/InstallingonUbuntu) hosts the maintainers' official documentation on installing globalmenu.

However, according to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/issues/detail?id=630), globalmenu doesn't compile at all in 10.10 and the project seems to be inactive. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/issues/attachmentText?id=630&aid=5886910873833590712&name=buildlog&token=dc0dd73d9c4772d7cbf3a92c79757fac#292)'s the error in the attached buildlog. You may want to try and fix the issue yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the effect of global menu. Install the package "indicator-applet-appmenu". This is the new appmenu used in the Ubuntu Netbook Edition. It is compatible with the normal Ubuntu session as well.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationMenu

Answer (score 0):

You can add this ppa - `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/globalmenu-team/ppa/ubuntu lucid main` manually to your software sources [The distro version is lucid there because they haven't updated their PPA to provide maverick packages, yet. But it doesn't matter. I've installed it on my system and its working perfect.] and use this command - `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-globalmenu gnome-applet-globalmenu`. Then add the global menu applet to your panel. :)

Comment: I suspect the user was looking for appmenu that is included in the netbook edition.

Comment: "Anyone knows how to install |||globalmenu||| on Ubuntu 10.10?" - This is what the OP said. And I can't understand why I was voted negative for this.

Comment: And the accepted answer says - "instead" use this. Even 'badp' was talking about globalmenu and I don't know why I had to bear the brunt. :(