# Global - Menu applet on maverick

Tags: gnome, globalmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the global appmenu (mac menu)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5951/how-do-i-install-the-global-appmenu-mac-menu)

Hi, where i can get working on ubuntu 10.10 global-menu applet?
Thx =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Global Menu Panel Applet" has not been ported to Maverick.  The applet used with unity is called "Indicator Applet Appmenu" available in Synaptic as indicator-applet-appmenu.  It is quite like the global menu applet.

That being said, I prefer the "Global Menu Panel Applet" as it is more customizable than the "Indicator Applet Appmenu."  To use the "Global Menu Panel Applet" I enabled the lucid ppa from the global-menu team:

https://launchpad.net/~globalmenu-team/+archive/ppa

NOTE: at this time (2011-2-21) this repository is still only listing lucid, not maverick.  It works fine in maverick.  Make sure you check your repository listing after you add the ppa and change it from maverick to lucid.

Between "Global Menu Panel Applet" and "Windows Buttons" applet available from this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~tsbarnes/+archive/misc/ I've finally achieved a panel that doubles as the title bar and menu bar of maximized apps.  This is saving a lot of screen space on a net book screen, yet lets me keep a normal panel at the top of the screen rather than using unity.

I hope that helps you out.

Here is a screenshot (attached to an external monitor . . . my netbook does not have a 1280x1024 screen :-)  ).

Mark

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to get it running von Oneiric and XFCE4.8 - have also tried lots of other things, like using xfapplet (an old one, it's not in the repo anymore)

Comment: Try https://web.archive.org/web/20150907070609/http://gtk-apps.org/content/show.php/OMG+!+XFCE+Global+Menu+[Oneiric+Only]?content=146102  It is for Oneiric only, but worked great for me last night. ~MO

Answer (score 2):

following the instructions under Ubuntu Desktop Installation on this wiki page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationMenu will get you global menu on maverick