# Is there a global menu for the XFCE panel?

Tags: xfce, globalmenu, xfce-panel

It would be very useful, and am thinking of switching to XFCE for the speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *This instructionswork in 11.10 and earlier*

No and yes. There is not one currently supported just for xfce that works (an old one exists, but is broke-see below).  However, you can use the "xfce-xfapplet-plugin" xfce plugin (listed in synaptic) to put the "gnome-applet-globalmenu" or the "indicator-applet-appmenu" onto the xfce panel.

See my answer at the following link to add the "gnome-applet-globalmenu" to your setup.  The instructions are for the gnome panel, but if you use the the plugin I mentioned above, you can add the "gnome-applet-globalmenu" to your xfce panel. It is a bit flaky.  I found the "indicator-applet-appmenu" works better with xfce while the "gnome-applet-globalmenu" works better with the gnome-panel.  Your mileage may vary.

[Global - Menu applet on maverick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11490/global-menu-applet-on-maverick/11591#11591)

The ppa mentioned in the link also adds a listing in synaptic for an "xfce4-global-menu applet", but it does NOT work and according to the README is no longer supported.

Here is a screenshot of it in action (yes, I like a mac-ish look):
[image: xfce with "indicator-applet-appmenu" in panel]

Comment: Is that XFCE? How did you remove the menubar from the windows?

Comment: @John Yes, that is xfce 4.8 from the koshi ppa:  https://launchpad.net/~koshi/+archive/xfce-4.8  The menu automatically went to the panel when I added the indicator-applet-appmenu to the xfce panel.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working on Oneiric. Anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for Ubuntu 14.04, 14.10 or 15.04 and its variants (such as Linux Mint 17.*)**

There is a global menu plugin/system called [TopMenu](https://gitorious.org/topmenu/pages/Home) which works on Xfce and MATE. You can find precompiled packages and instructions on [Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/use-global-menu-in-xubuntu-or-linux.html).

There are limitations, however. It will not work with Java applications, Chrom(e|ium) or LibreOffice. There are also graphical glitches with most Xfce themes. The only known compatible Xfce themes are [Numix](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/05/numix-theme-for-ubuntulinux-mintother.html) and the default Linux Mint theme.