# How do I enable the globalmenu / appmenu on Xfce or LXDE?

Tags: 11.10, xfce, appmenu, lxde

I have tried various tricks I could find to install the global menu on Xfce and LXDE on the latest Oneiric, but nothing worked. Does anyone have an idea on how to do that? Thanks.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- the [gnome global menu panel plugin (for lucid)](https://launchpad.net/~globalmenu-team/+archive/ppa) via the [xfapplet plugin](https://launchpad.net/~koshi/+archive/xfce-4.8) (not in the official repos anymore) that can embed GNOME plugins into the Xfce panel - unfortunately, the globalmenu doesn't show up in the xfapplet list of available GNOME plugins (there's only one item in it)
- all instructions from an [older question about globalmenu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5951/how-do-i-install-the-global-appmenu-mac-menu) and its [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11490/global-menu-applet-on-maverick)
- compiling manually the latest version from [gnome2-globalmenu](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/)
- there is another question [along with a solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27189/is-there-a-global-menu-for-the-xfce-panel) for Xfce 4.8, but it's not working on Oneiric. It is also proposing to install the global menu applet from GNOME using it via xfapplet.
- I've even found an [Xfce-plugin for the global menu](http://ppa.launchpad.net/globalmenu-team/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-globalmenu/), but it keeps crashing when I add it to the panel - also I could not install all the packages due to some unmet dependencies
- I've added some code to ~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc as described in [10. of the FAQ of gnome2-globalmenu](http://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/wiki/FAQ), though I'm not sure what effect this should have.

Comment: Please elaborate on the various tricks you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### PPA method

- Add the following ppa **ppa:the-warl0ck-1989/xfce-appmenu-plugin**

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:the-warl0ck-1989/xfce-appmenu-plugin`

- Install

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xfce4-appmenu-plugin indicator-appmenu appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt`

- Right-click on an empty part of the top XFCE panel and choose **Panel** > **Add New Items** > **App Menu plugin**

---

### Manual method

1. **Install the missing dependencies**. In a terminal : `sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt`
2. **Install the app menu** : download [this deb](https://gitorious.org/xfce-appmenu-plugin/xfce-appmenu-plugin/trees/master/binary/x86) and open it with the software center
3. **Enable app menu for firefox and thunderbird**. In a terminal : `sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk3 firefox-globalmenu thunderbird-globalmenu`
4. Right-click on an empty part of the top XFCE panel and choose **Panel** > **Add New Items** > **App Menu plugin**

*[Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/how-to-enable-ubuntus-global-menu-in-xubuntu-11-10/)*

Comment: Just saw it this morning :-) now trying to compile it for 64bit, anyone tried?

Comment: @JohannPhilippStrathausen did you try `sudo dpkg --force-architecture xfce4-appmenu-plugin_0.10-1_i386.deb` ?

Comment: No didn't try that, maybe it would have worked. Instead, I compiled it via `./configure; make; sudo make install`, had to install one additional libindicator-dev or something like that because it was complaining about it in the configure phase, log out, log in, then add it to the panel, working nicely :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! Just wanted to share the link of the source tar ball for compiling: https://web.archive.org/web/20150907070609/http://gtk-apps.org/content/show.php/OMG+!+XFCE+Global+Menu+[Oneiric+Only]?content=146102 Furthermore the script asks for an unresolved dependency which apparently cannot be satisfied, the package name to be installed is actually xfce4-panel-dev

Comment: :( Frak! Doesn't work for me.

Says: Plugin "Indicator Appmenu Plugin" unexpectedly left the panel, do you want to restart it?. 

And offers me Execute (which brings up the same error again) and remove. Im using Ubuntu 11.10 x64.

Comment: @jesusiniesta how did you install the plugin (compiled or deb)? Johann was talking about a missing lib, maybe try `sudo apt-get install libindicator-dev`

Comment: Cannot download .deb file!!!!

Comment: @Ravi found a [new link](https://gitorious.org/xfce-appmenu-plugin/xfce-appmenu-plugin/trees/master/binary/x86)