# title bar in xfce panel

Tags: 11.10, xfce, titlebar

I have a netbook with Ubuntu Oneiric (11.10) installed with XFCE. Due to the limited vertical space available, I would like to have the title bar for a maximized window appear in the xfce panel. I use to be able to do this on Ubuntu 10.04 (GNOME2) with `maximus` and `window-picker-applet`. I'm not using GNOME Shell or Unity (including 2d) because they run too slow on my netbook.

I've looked at [How do I enable the globalmenu / appmenu on Xfce or LXDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66181/how-do-i-enable-the-globalmenu-appmenu-on-xfce-or-lxde). It doesn't help me though because it's only for getting the menu to appear in the panel (using `xfce4-appmenu-plugin`). Is there something similar but mimicking the title bar?  It appears as though `xfce4-xfapplet-plugin` has been removed in Ubuntu 11.10.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you are looking for but inorder to save space you could use xfce4-panel as wingpanel. `xfapplet` is somewhat dead project AFAIK. What you can do is make xfce4-panel as a wingpanel with minimal length and make it auto-increase.  In order to make panel movable do this:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/disable-struts -t bool -n -s true
```

And on panel preference, make panel length to minimal and enable auto-increase option:

[image]

You can do this for as many panel you have.

I usually have a single panel on the right-hand corner with notification area, indicator, session-button and application-menu and windows button control on the left-hand corner.

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/get-minimalistic-wingpanel-like-xfce4.html)