# appmenu on Xubuntu 12.10

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, globalmenu

Is there anyone who succesfully managed to use an `appmenu` (what was once called [Global Menu](https://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/) in Gnome 2.x) on Xubuntu 12.10?

[image]

Before answering please note that I tried with xfapplet (which is no longer available on 12.10) and with this package XFCE appmenu, which depends on the old libindicator6 (on 12.10 there's libindicator7).

Comment: What do you mean by "appmenu"? You have Xfce's `Applications Menu` and [`xfce4-whiskermenu`](http://gottcode.org/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin/). Are you looking for something else?

Comment: I was. Appmenu is the Ubuntu "answer" to what was once called [Global Menu](https://code.google.com/p/gnome2-globalmenu/) in Gnome 2.x.

However it does not matter anymore, this question is obsolete for me, since it is about a distro that is going to be discontinued soon.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what this Appmenu does. Could you provide a link in the original question?

Comment: I modified the previous comment :)

Comment: OK, thanks. I improved a little the original question. I'm interested myself in how to achieve this in Xfce, but I can't recall to have a read about a solution. (Maybe xfce4-indicator?)

Comment: Hmm, isn't this question a duplicate of [How do I enable the globalmenu / appmenu on XFCE or LXDE?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66181/how-do-i-enable-the-globalmenu-appmenu-on-xfce-or-lxde) ?

Comment: As I said in my question, that method (installation of `xfce4-appmenu-plugin`, aka Xfce appmenu) is not working because it relies on libindicator6, while in Ubu 12.10 there was libindicator7.

Comment: Have you tried creating a personal PPA, copying the package from ppa:the-warl0ck-1989/xfce-appmenu-plugin to your PPA and choosing to `rebuild` for your distribution? This would instruct Launchpad to rebuild using the available libindicator library.

Answer (score 0):

Since this package is already available in the [ppa:the-warl0ck-1989/xfce-appmenu-plugin](https://launchpad.net/~the-warl0ck-1989/+archive/xfce-appmenu-plugin), you can proceed as follows:

1. Create a personal PPA using your Launchpad account.
2. Go to [ppa:the-warl0ck-1989/xfce-appmenu-plugin](https://launchpad.net/~the-warl0ck-1989/+archive/xfce-appmenu-plugin) and access `View package details > Copy packages`.
3. Select the desired package (say, the one for `Precise`) and copy it to your personal PPA. Change `Destination series` to whatever you need (here, `12.10` or `Quantal`). Ensure that `Rebuild the copied sources` is selected, which will allow the binaries to be built using the available libraries on the chosen distro.
4. Click `Copy Packages`.

These instructions are generic and will work for any package that is already available on a Launchpad PPA, and for any distribution currently supported by Launchpad. They can fail, especially if the chosen distribution does not provide a needed library or a specific version of a library.

But it seems to work in this case. For proof of point, check out the `xfce4-appmenu-plugin` that I copied to [my testing PPA](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/collection). (Ignore that the `version` string contains `0.10-0~2~precise1`: the package was built against `Quantal`, as you can check in `View package details` in the `Series` column.)