# Getting a Global Menu on Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, xfce, menu, globalmenu

How do I get a true global menu on Xubuntu or Ubuntu/Gnome 3 Classic 13.10? 
I don't want the Unity autohiding menu, just a horizontal global menu that lives in a toolbar on top of the screen. I know there was a PPA for an old version of Ubuntu, but I'm looking for a solution that will work on 13.10.

Comment: I’m fine with a solution for 12.04, no matter which desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

The [Xfce Appmenu Plugin](https://launchpad.net/xfce4-appmenu-plugin) looks rather abandoned and currently unmaintained. I tried to get it working under Ubuntu Precise, but failed. You can try to install `xfce4-appmenu-plugin` that I copied to [my testing PPA](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/collection), but I would expect it not to work for you.

For details see:

- [appmenu on Xubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237326/appmenu-on-xubuntu-12-10/404960#404960)