# Lubuntu / LXDE make the panel like in Ubuntu / MacOS

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, panel, lxde, lxpanel

How to make Lubuntu or LXDE panel to be on the top and behave like Ubuntu / MacOS panel (having the application menu placed to panel)

I have a small laptop screen and I like this ability of Ubuntu very much. I use LXDE with Lubuntu just because it takes far less system resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what your system is but for a simple Lubuntu system (which comes with LXDE and other requisites), clicking anywhere in the blank area right at the top or the bottom of the screen should bring up this:

[image: clicking in blank area]

Then, in that window, clicking on "Panel Settings" should bring up this:

[image: Panel Settings]

The options are self-explanatory here and the choices are quite a few.

As I said, this is with a proper Lubuntu installation.

Comment: I found it's not possible to do with Luuntu. The first thing I tried is this properties. I already put the panel to the top. But the application menu's like "File", "Edit", "Toos" are not added to a panel, like it's done in Ubuntu or MacOS

Comment: Aha! You want the global menu. I haven't come across anything about adding the global menu to Lubuntu.

Comment: The closest I get is [this Ask Ubuntu question](http://askubuntu.com/q/66181/25656) but it relates to 11.10 and focuses on Xubuntu.